# Setting Date using TwitterR Search

Tags: r, api, twitter

Since the free Twitter API only allows you to search the last 7 days worth of data I am trying to automatically set the dates for those 7 days. When I leave the date fields blank I get random historical tweets.

```
#### Pepsi 

#Dates for API 
s <- as.Date(Sys.Date()-7, format = "%Y/%m/%d") 
e <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y/%m/%d") 

#Pepsi Twitter Data 
pepsitweet <- searchTwitter("Pepsi",n=1000,lang="en", since = "s", until = "e") 
tweets1 <- twListToDF(pepsitweet)
```

Error

> 1000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
>
> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
>         character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to check out Mike Kearney's rtweet package, which seems to be much smoother than twitteR: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/intro.html

I've had a cron job mining tweets on a daily basis since November and it's performed beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put quotes around the variables `s` and `e`. R is interpreting them as strings.

```
pepsitweet <- searchTwitter("Pepsi", n = 1000, lang = "en", since = s, until = e)
```

Comment: I'd also look at the `rtweet` package in preference to `twitteR`.